# X-axis displayed names incomplete and repeating

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

When I run the code below I receive a duplication within the X axis

```
ax = df.plot.line(x="Brand", y="Range", legend=False)
ax2 = ax.twinx()
df.plot.line(x="Brand", y="Seats", ax=ax2, legend=False, color="#d86e39")
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
ax.figure.legend()
plt.show()
```

The libraries I am using are:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from plotly.offline import iplot
import plotly as py
import plotly.tools as tls

%matplotlib inline
```

[image: The image shows the repeating x-axis names]

Comment: Hi @eglease, I really appreciate the edit as someone knew to programming.

Comment: What libraries are you using? Please [edit] and add the tags for them. You might want to add the imports too. If it helps, it looks like Pandas, matplotlib, and Seaborn.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips. I'm a bit out of my depth, but you'll probably want to make a [mre] including some example input (data), and the current outputs.

Comment: Hi @wjandrea, As advised I have now added in the libraries. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Please share what your plot currently looks like.

Comment: Hi @jared, I have a screenshot of one that works and the other which isn't as expected how can I attach both?

Comment: Hi @jared, I have attached a screenshot as requested.

Comment: What is the duplication that you're referring to?

Comment: Hi Jared, Thanks for your reply, the duplication is referring to the X-Axis naming repetition. In my CSV file, there are additional brand names but for some reason, a reduced list appears with repeated brand names as shown in the screenshot with Tesla.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please can my question be reopened as the duplicate claims do not answer and are differentiated from my questions.

Comment: Some values in the 'Brand' column likely have leading or trailing spaces, which need to be removed. `df.Brand.unique()` will show all the unique values in the column. Also, it’s not an appropriate visualization for a lineplot, continuous data, to have a categorical, discrete, xaxis. The question lacks a complete [mre] and cannot be answered further.

Comment: Hi @TrentonMcKinney, Thank you for answer. I understand something like a date field would be better suited. This is just an example chart I have created using my assignment data in the process of learning Python. I will definitely try the code you have mentioned and hopefully it resolves my issue. Have a nice and safe rest of your week.